# Is there a single documentation page that shows what all LWC lighting-input-field types look like?

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputfield

I'd like to share with our designers the available "easy" input **field** options but haven't found a good reference link to give them. Is there one?

(This [Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) reference is good for the overall component set but doesn't provide `lighting-input-field` detail.)

Comment: In the documentation link there is a section for field types supported, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @RedDevil I am looking for a set of pictures of what each one looks like when rendered.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/

Comment: @PhilHawthorn Interesting to see, but it is the field output I'm looking for (e.g. mult-select picklist) more than the HTML 5 input field variations. (I've added "field" in bold to the question to be clearer.)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into the [Picklist widget CSS page](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/picklist/#site-main-content) in the [Lightning Design System website](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/). It shows the many ways to represent a picklist in with the design system, which is used by Salesforce. I believe the closest is the "Open - Options Selected" example.

Comment: Thanks, but looking for a single page with all the field types presented.